# flex property not working in IE

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have been unable to determine why flexbox is not working in IE 11.

For testing, I sourced a very simple flexbox layout from CodePen and have pasted the information below.

Chrome works as intended; IE11 fails.

Image of layout-success running on Chrome:

[image]

Image of layout-failure on IE11

[image]

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  background: hotpink;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid seashell;
  color: seashell;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: auto;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 180px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

http://codepen.io/hankthewhale/pen/IdKkB?editors=110

Answer (score 59, accepted):

IE has a problem parsing the `flex` property.

Here are a few workarounds that have worked for me:

- **Use the long-hand properties instead of the shorthand.**

  Instead of something like this: `flex: 0 0 35%`.

  Try this:

  - `flex-grow: 0`
  - `flex-shrink: 0`
  - `flex-basis: 35%`

---

- **Make sure `flex-shrink` is enabled.**

  So instead of this: `flex: 0 0 35%`

  Try this: `flex: 0 1 35%`

  (In other cases `flex-shrink` needs to be *disabled*: [Flex item overlaps another item in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49365551/3597276))

---

- **Careful with percentage and unitless values with `flex-basis`**

  This may depend on your version of IE11. Behavior appears to vary.

  Try these variations:

  - `flex: 1 1 0`
  - `flex: 1 1 0px`
  - `flex: 1 1 0%`

**Beware!** Certain css minifiers will replace `0px` with `0`, which can be a really annoying thing to debug (however, they won't change `0%` for some reason).

More details here:

- [Image behavior within flexbox (rows embedded in columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33975539/3597276)
- [Why does shorthand flex property behave differently than long hand properties in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43100897/3597276)

---

- **Instead of `flex: 1` use `flex: auto` (or add in `flex-basis: auto`)**

  If you're using `flex: 1` in `flex-direction: row` (such as on larger screens), and you switch to `flex-direction: column` in a media query (let's say for mobile devices), you may find that your flex items collapse.

  In your media query, add `flex-basis: auto`. This will override the `flex-basis` value in the `flex: 1` rule (which is usually `0`, `0px` or `0%`, depending on the browser).

  Using `flex: auto` should also work, which is short for:

  - `flex-grow: 1`
  - `flex-shrink: 1`
  - `flex-basis: auto`

---

- **Use old-fashion `width` / `height` properties instead of `flex`**.

---

- **Use `block` layout instead of `flex` layout.**

  You don't need to completely abandon flex layout. But for a particular container you may be able to get the job done with `display: block` instead of `display: flex; flex-direction: column`.

  For example, in needing to use the [padding trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1495407/3597276) to responsively embed a video in a flex item, the obstacle I faced was that [some browsers don't work well with percentage padding (or margin) in a flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36783190/3597276).

  To make it work I switched the `display` value on the flex item from this:

  ```
  /* a flex item, also a nested flex container */
  #footer-container > article {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
  }
  ```

  to this:

  ```
  #footer-container > article {
      display: block;
  }
  ```

Comment: Hello! do you know of a polyfill that converts the flex from shorthand to longhand?

Comment: Moving from shorthand to the multi-line definition was what worked for my situation.

Answer (score 10):

For me, using

```
  flex: 1 1 auto;
```

instead of

```
  flex: 1;
```

solved the flex issue on IE 11.

Comment: Well, that is what ___Instead of `flex: 1` use `flex: auto`___ means, as `flex: auto` translates to exactly that, `flex: 1 1 auto`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `flex:1 0 auto;`. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

As in @Michael_B answer, limit the growth with Flexbox `flex` property: `flex: 0 1 (1/n - b)` taken in % value, where `n` is the number of flex items in a row and `b` is the gap that you want to see between flex items in IE.

On the flex items along with `flex` property above use the `max-width` property with percentage value of `1/n - b`.

In your case the generalized CSS for the flex item would be:

```
li {
    // ... the remaining code from your snippet
    // Calculate the following manually and insert or use CSS preprocessor that does math for you.
    // See the formula explanation above.
    max-width: (your flex container max-width / 2) * 100% - b; 
    flex: 0 1 (your flex container max-width / 2) * 100% - b;
}
```

In actual case with 5 items / row there will be `(1/5) * 100% - 1% = 19%` => `max-width: 19%` and `flex: 0 1 19%;`.

Play with `b` parameter to make flex items short enough to allow `flex: wrap;` work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the CSS minifier rejects the `px` unit of the last argument in `-ms-flex` shorthand rule, I tried using `%` unit and it works fine.