# How do browsers calculate width when child depends on parent, and parent's depends on child's

Tags: html, css, width, css-grid

I'm experiencing various glitches, weird rendering artifacts and so forth on my React application and was wondering about the way defining dimensions works from a browser's point of view.

Let's say I have a grid display, and there's a `div` which has `grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr` and a child `div` which has spans `grid-column: 2 / 3` - in other words spanning in the `auto` area of the parent grid.

As I understand, the value `auto` in grid template columns defines the column to be sized to fit its contents.

Now let's add an `img` with the `max-width` set to `100%` - in other words, we don't want to exceed the size of the parent container.

However, the parent container's width is determined by the `auto` rule - so how can the browser let the child know to take up 100%?

Example

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.box>div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  margin: 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div style="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" style="max-width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain this, I will start with a more simplified example that will produce the same output:

```html
<div style="display:inline-block">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x100">
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x100" style="max-width:100%">
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block">
  <!-- even a big explicit width specified won't change the behavior -->
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x100" style="wdith:2000px;max-width:100%">
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x100" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

We have an `inline-block` element so its width depend on its content and the use of `max-width:100%` (or `width:100%`) will give us the strange result.

To understand this, we need to refer to the specification and more precisely [Percentage Sizing](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#percentage-sizing) section where we can read:

> Sometimes the size of a percentage-sized **box’s containing block** depends on the intrinsic size contribution of the **box itself**, creating a **cyclic dependency**. When calculating the intrinsic size contribution of such a box (including any calculations for a content-based automatic minimum size), a cyclic percentage—that is, a percentage value that would resolve against a containing block size which itself depends on that percentage—is resolved specially:

Our box is the image and the containing block is the `inline-block` div. The image is a replaced element so we need to follow the (b) and (c) to identify the *max-content contribution* and the *min-content contribution*

> b. Likewise, if the box is replaced, then the entire value of any max size property or preferred size property specified as an expression containing a percentage that is cyclic is treated *for the purpose of calculating the box’s max-content contributions* only as that property’s **initial value**.

Considering `max-width`/`width` as auto will keep the max-content contribution the same (`1000px` in our case). What will change is the min-content contribution:

> c. If the box is replaced, a cyclic percentage in the value of any max size property or preferred size property (width/max-width/height/max-height), **is resolved against zero when calculating the min-content contribution in the corresponding axis**.

So the min-content contribution of the image will become `0` and no more `1000px` which was the initial min-content contribution based on its intrinsic dimension (related: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#intrinsic-sizes) and all the trick is here!

Now our inline-block is a shrink-to-fit element and the following algorithm apply:

> Then the shrink-to-fit width is: `min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width)`. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width)</sup>

the contribution of the image will vary from `0` to `1000px` so the browser will pick the value that will avoid any overflow (the *available width* part) and not bigger than `1000px` (the *min* part)

Without the use of percentage the min-content of the image was `1000px` so the browser is obliged to use a value between `1000px` and `1000px` as *preferred minimum width* which will give the div the intrinsic size width of the image.

All this is only the calculation of the div width. After this, we consider the calculated width as a reference for our percentage value.

We can also consider different value and the logic will be the same:

```css
div {
  border:2px solid red;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x100">
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x100" style="max-width:80%">
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x100" style="width:50%">
</div>
```

---

The above logic apply the same way to your code since your column is set to `auto` which means that its size is based on its content and is also the containing block of the image.

Comment: Since you asked, this all looks correct to me, and rigorously covered.

Comment: Yes, and in CSS2.1 that behavior was explicitly undefined.: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#x9 "If the containing block's width depends on this element's width, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1."