# Browsers renders grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 0fr); as grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 0);

Tags: html, css, razor, css-grid

In my ASP.NET MVC app I need the buttons to have the same width. If one button is wider than the other, the smaller one stretches to the same width as the larger one.

For this I wrote next CSS code:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .xxx-container .yyy-container .zzz-container .buttons-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 0fr);
  }
}
```

when I run my app locally all works OK:

[image]

But when I deploy it to preprod in browser(any) devtools I see
`grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 0);` instead of `grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 0fr);`. So I'm getting next result:

[image]

What can be the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: why using 0fr? doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: if I use 1fr, it will stretch the buttons across the entire width of the block, with 0fr it will stretch everything to a wide button

Comment: I am not saying you should use 1fr but using 0fr to achieve what you want is a hacky way, it can be done differently

Comment: 0 is the same value no matter what unit you use in CSS. 0fr == 0%  == 0px == 0em.

Comment: @HereticMonkey not really, they are different especially when dealing with percentage or calc() (Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62523544/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/54010222/8620333)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah, I went a little overboard with 0%, but for pretty much any `<length>`, outside of a function, '0<unit>' can be replaced by `0`. I mean, that's why the CSS tab in the inspector is eliding the unit in the OP's case. I use 0 pretty much everywhere to save a couple bytes in CSS. Never had an issue (but I didn't get into the situations those questions were about).