# Why doesn't percentage padding / margin work on flex items in Firefox and Edge?

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I want to have a square div inside a flexbox. So I use:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
.inner {
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <a>hehe</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works fine in Chrome. But in Firefox, the parent squeezes to just one line.

How do I solve this in Firefox? I use version 44.

You can also view the code at https://jsbin.com/lakoxi/edit?html,css

Comment: **Margins or padding of  flex items works fine** on both browsers now. To make the inner element "Square", has to remove the element `<a>` or leave it from layout (such as `position: absolute`) , because it has intrinsic height.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

***2018 Update***

The flexbox specification has been updated.

> [**4.2. Flex Item Margins and Paddings**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#item-margins)
>
> Percentage margins and paddings on flex items, like those on block
> boxes, are resolved against the inline size of their containing block,
> e.g. left/right/top/bottom percentages all resolve against their
> containing block’s width in horizontal writing modes.

---

***Original Answer - applies to FF and Edge versions released before 2018***

*From the [flexbox specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#item-margins):*

> **Authors should avoid using percentages in paddings or margins on flex items entirely, as they will get different behavior in different browsers.**

Here's some more:

> [**4.2. Flex Item Margins and Paddings**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#item-margins)
>
> Percentage margins and paddings on flex items can be resolved against either:
>
> - their own axis (left/right percentages resolve against width, top/bottom resolve against height), or,
> - the inline axis (left/right/top/bottom percentages all resolve against width)
>
> **A User Agent must choose one of these two behaviors.**
>
> Note: This variance sucks, but it accurately captures the current state of the world (no consensus among implementations, and no consensus within the CSSWG). It is the CSSWG’s intention that browsers will converge on one of the behaviors, at which time the spec will be amended.

Comment: @Lichtbringer, I was able to use `display: block` to get around the issue on one site. See the last bullet point in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39310591/3597276

Comment: Not a real workaround to me, as I "need" to use flexbox.

Comment: @Lichtbringer There is a workaround, check my answer

Comment: The spec has now been amended: UAs must resolve percentage padding/margin against the inline size: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#item-margins

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Michael_B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36783414/2827823), here is a possible workaround.

When using percent we often relate that to the viewport width, so with that in mind, viewport units `vw`/`vh` can be an option, since it works similar (responsive).

Stack snippet

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
.inner {
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  padding-bottom: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <a>hehe</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

If a square is a must, and viewport units or script can't be used, here is another trick using a dummy image.

*Note, as image also a SVG or a Base64 could be used as a `datauri` to save an extra round trip to the server*

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
.inner {
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
.inner img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/10" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a real workaround. I mean yes, in certain constellations it may be what you're after, but if you want the dimensions be reliant on the parent node then working with viewport units is tedious, because you (probably) need to change other nodes as well then.

Comment: @Lichtbringer Thats why I wrote _"...we often relate that to the viewport width, so with that in mind..."_ and since there is no other way to get a _percentage based_ value, it is the only CSS workaround

Comment: @Lichtbringer I also added a 2nd sample to my answer