# flexbox wrapping columns in internet explorer 11

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have 5 columns which i need to display in one row.
The columns display in one row in chrome & safari. 
In IE11 the last column wraps onto a second row which is not what I want.

```
.col { flex: 0 1 19.4%; margin-right: .6%; }
```

I have 1px borders on my columns. When I remove the borders all columns fit nicely in one row again.

Do i need to specify which box-model ie11 should use?

Comment: The flexbox specification advises against using percentage values for padding/margin: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36783414/3597276

Comment: Have you tried adding `flex-wrap: nowrap;` to the flex parent?

Comment: I switched to ems which fixed the issue in ie11