# Applying margin to flex items

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

So I got this three column layout example from stackoverflow, but I'm trying to get both columns and rows using flexbox.

My ultimate goal is to have a three column layout (the left side be pictures, and the two columns to the right to be text).

However, I need everything to be lined up (the text and the images be aligned on the same axis).

But my problem is that when I try and space out the elements in the columns using `margin-bottom`, only the text column one is working (and not the image one) and I can't figure out why.

I want the left column `margin-bottom` to work as well. But even when I add `margin-bottom` for all columns only the ones with the divs work.

Should I put my images in divs as well?

Here's an image of the problem I'm facing:

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  order: 1;
  background: red;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  order: 3;
  background: green;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.right {
  order: 2;
  background: yellow;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  .left {
    flex-basis: 1;
    order: 1;
  }
  .middle {
    flex-basis: 1;
    order: 2;
  }
  .right {
    flex-basis: 1;
    order: 3;
  }
}
.left,
.right,
.middle * {
  margin-bottom: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="cat1.jpeg" alt="cat">
    <img src="cat1.jpeg" alt="cat">
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="box">`
      <p>texteiehiefief texteiehiefief texteiehiefief texteiehiefief</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">`
      <p>texteiehiefief texteiehiefief texteiehiefief texteiehiefief</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, you are trying to display tabular information, so using a table would be a more appropriate choice than using flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with the selector you're using to apply the bottom margin:

```
.left,
.right,
.middle * {
    margin-bottom: 25%;
}
```

This selector says:

- Apply the margin to `.left`
- Apply the margin to `.right`
- Apply the margin to *all descendants of `.middle`*

That's why your text boxes are getting the margin – they're descendants of `.middle` – and your images are not – they're descendants of `.left`, but `.left` in your CSS isn't targeting descendants.

Make this adjustment:

```
.left *,
.right,
.middle * {
    margin-bottom: 25%;
}
```

**ALSO, KEEP IN MIND** that the flexbox specification discourages use of percentages on margin and padding when dealing with flex items ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36783414/3597276)).

Comment: How do you recommend I space out the images? It seems like they are stretching. I want the images to resize to fit mobile so I put max-width: 100% for .left img but that's not working and I also want to space out the images. When I do align-items: space-between it's not working.

Comment: `align-items` works along the [**cross-axis**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276). When `flex-direction` is `column`, like in those containers, it aligns horizontally. For vertical alignment use `justify-content`: https://jsfiddle.net/6aeo7Ls1/