# Maintain aspect ratio of flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a page which is supposed to emulate a letter size piece of paper. The page is basically split into two parts, the top nav-bar and the the main part of the page.

My code currently looks like this:

```css
html, body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";
  font-size: 1em;
}
.hor-nav {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
  height: 64px;
}
.main {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
.page {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: 16px;
  padding-right: 77.27975270479134%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hor-nav">
  test
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="page">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

I have been trying to make use of the "padding %" trick but it does not seem to be working for.

> My end goal is the "paper" (an emulation of 11in tall and 8.5in wide piece of letter paper) to *fill* the remaining *vertical/height* space after the nav-bar (the grey bar at the top of the above snippet) *while* at the same time keep the aspect ratio of 11:8.5 (or 1.294:1).

To fill the vertical space I am using a flex box and the paper is a flex-item with the property: `flex: 1 1 auto;`. This grows or shinks the paper to accommodate the change of the webpage, however, it also effects it's width.

The most successful I have gotten is getting rid of the `flex: 1 1 auto;` and using `width: 77.2%;` (what I calculated to be the width of a piece of "paper," however this number might not be correct), except that this did not work, as it did not hold the aspect ratio, but instead just made sure the width was only 77.2% of the containing element.

*note: as you can see from my above snippet, I am using a `padding` as I attempted the [padding trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css) for this but as @Michael_B pointed out this does not work. As I have no other working code I have not been able to replace it out yet.*

> **Does anyone know how to keep a flex-item aspect ratio while at the same time growing it's *height* to fill the rest of the document (of course, with the margins)**

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear about your objective, but here's a possible step forward: [*Don't use percentage-based padding (or margin) on flex items:*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36783414/3597276).

Comment: @Michael_B thank you. I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an [aspect ratio calculator](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/), we can determine that 8.5 x 11 is equivalent to 8 x 10 (80% x 100%).

Using CSS [viewport percentage units](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths), we can set an element's height to emulate letter-size paper on all screen sizes.

This is the basic code:

```
.page {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 80vh;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.hor-nav {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
  height: 64px;
}
.main { }

.page {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 16px;
  height: calc(100vh - 32px - 64px);  /* height, less margins, less nav height */
  width: calc(80vh - 32px - 64px);
}
```

```html
<div class="hor-nav">test</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="page">test</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmso5dv1/)

Comment: I knew it had something to do with viewports, but I couldn't quite piece it together! I added `.main { margin: auto; }` to really seal the deal and it works perfectly! Thank you! @Michael_B does it again!

Comment: For anyone coming to this question later, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css) has a better answer for modern browsers! (the `aspect-ratio` property)