# css display flex not working properly on chrome and safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I used flexbox properties to make my section look like this:

[image]

It works fine on Chrome but I noticed a few differences when I checked firefox and safari.

This is how chrome looks like:
[image]

But on Firefox, I am not managing to apply to margin of 1% like I want as the red signal shows:

[image]

And on safari, the boxes are all one after the other:

[image]

It is a WordPress Site and not live yet. But here is my html structure:

```
    <section id="services">

        // here goes the title of the container

        <div class="main-container col-lg">  

               // here go all the box

         <div class="services-container">    

               // this one of the boxes              
         </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And the CSS:

```
#services {
    background-image: url("img/Services-background.jpg");
    background-color: red;
}
.col-lg {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: initial;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.services-container {
    color: #d6d6d6;
    margin: 1%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 30%;
}
```

How Can I make this work on all browsers?

Comment: Flexbox works fine in modern browsers. It's just new and some browsers require special attention. In this case, [**using a percentage margin is causing the problem**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36783414/3597276).

Comment: For Safari, see [**Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276) and [**Flexbox code working on all browsers except Safari. Why?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35137085/3597276).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you not use flexbox, but floats instead.
Delete all the flex properties your css should look like this:

```
#services{
    background-image: url(img/Services-background.jpg);
    overflow: auto;
}
.services-container {
    color: #d6d6d6;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
}
```

Then you can add the rest of the styling. It will work on all browsers.

Comment: I am using float property and works on all browsers indeed.Appreciate

Comment: Quick 2019 update , using flexbox in print css still behaves unpredictable

Answer (score 4):

The best way to ensure that flex is working equally on all browsers is to use prefixes.

[Here's the chart from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility) showing you the different browser prefixes available for flex box (and general browser support notices)

Comment: The link seems to jump around weirdly, just click on the _Browser compatibility_ link on the right sidebar to see the table with the prefixes.

Answer (score 3):

```
 display: flex;
-webkit-display: flex;
-moz-display: flex;
-ms--display: flex;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the `HTML version` may be the reason *(it was in my case)*:

I looked for `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the `source code`.  My `HTML` turned out to `4.0 something` and that was the reason (most probably) that `flex` did not work.  Once that was changed, it worked well.

Good luck...