# justify-content: space-between with equal space between first and last items also

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to use flexbox to set-up a simple elastic* grid...

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

...but **I want the outer margins to be equal to the space between the items.**

*By "elastic" I mean that the widths not fixed. They are all percentages, and so different total widths at different screen widths.

This does not appear to be the default behavior of `justify-content: space-between`. It generates equal space "around" each item but the space does not collapse the way margins do. So the result is that the "between" spaces are twice as wide as the far right and left (assuming you're flex-direction is `row`).

In the sketch below, the first diagram is what `justify-content: space-between` does naturally. Notice widths A and B. The second diagram is what I want (only one consistent gutter C).

Is this possible with flexbox?

[image]

**Update**

I would like to avoid having to add "row" wrapping elements if possible. The pseudo element solution sounds like just the ticket (see answers below), but let's work it out so that the items can be of an undetermined number (and wrap onto new rows)

Comment: Love the illustrations btw.

Comment: @Michael_B I'd actually like that to differ based on breakpoints. That's why I'm trying to avoid the row wrappers. As a simple proof of concept let's say 2/row up to 1000px and then 3/row. Do you think we can do this using `:nth-child()`? Or maybe it doesn't matter...

Comment: Posted a 3:rd sample, using breakpoints

Comment: Just came across this searching for another issue. Was `justify-content: space-around;` not an option?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `space-between` with pseudo elements from the parent

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex > div {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  height: 100px; width: 100px;
}
.flex:before,.flex:after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this is clever!! Can you explain briefly why it works? Are the pseudo elements being considered as flex items? I would have expected them to "appear" before/after the flex context... but I guess not?

Comment: @emersonthis yep exactly. The first time I learned that this works was on accident when I spent like an hour trying to debug a flex layout, only to learn the :before and :after elements were being treated as flex children.

Comment: @emersonthis but it's important to remember that the pseudo elements behave like children of the element they're associated with. For example, you can do `div { position: relative; } div:after { position: absolute; }` and the `:after` pseudo element will be positioned absolutely relative to the div. Or `div { border: 1px solid black; } div:before { content: 'foo'; }`, and "foo" will be inside of the border. Those elements behave like a child element.

Answer (score 1):

How about using 0 width pseudo elements before and after the items?

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid #C55;
}

.column {
  flex: 1 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #C55;
}

.even:before, .even:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
no side spacing:
<div class="container">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
<br>
side spacing:
<div class="container even">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of pseudo-elements will accomplish that:

```css
flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: orangered;
}

flex-item {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

flex-container::after {
  content: '';
}

flex-container::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

Most, if not all, browsers interpret pseudo-elements on a flex container to be flex items. The `::before` pseudo is the first item, and the `::after` is the last.

Here's a reference from Firefox documentation:

> [In-flow `::after` and `::before` pseudo-elements are now flex
>   items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/23#CSS)
>   ([bug 867454](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=867454)).

The code above works because `justify-content: space-between` now factors in five flex items, but the first and last have 0 width.

I'm not sure this can be made to work in a *multi-line container* (`flex-wrap: wrap`) with pure CSS. You can try using `auto` margins on flex items instead of `justify-content` on the container. Otherwise, JavaScript.

Comment: Do you know any specifics on the browser support for this technique? Basically, which browsers _don't_ consider pseudo-elements flex items?

Comment: I believe all major browsers have the same behavior.

Comment: Awesome. I stumbled across this, which suggests that a few (older) flavors of IE11 were buggy regarding this. But sounds like it's pretty safe for production these days: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1058330/ie11-will-not-apply-flexbox-on-pseudo-elements

Comment: If I try the `flex-wrap: wrap` technique with `margin: auto` what should the `justify-content` setting be? Default?

Comment: I'm not sure what your ultimate goals are, so I don't know if `auto` margins will work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/uu9chyey/1/

Comment: My ultimate goal is for (in the diagram above) the **C** gaps and the item widths to be percentages so the proportions remain the same at all break points. Does that make sense?

Comment: So for example, I want a 3 item grid layout with each item occupying 20% of the space and 10% gutters.

Comment: That part I know. But what's supposed to happen on the last row, when there are less items to fill the row? `auto` margins will center them. `space-between` will have different behavior.

Comment: Last item(s) centered would be okay. In a perfect world it would sit flushed left. But I don't think that's possible, or worth overcomplicating the solution to achieve.

Comment: What do you think? https://jsfiddle.net/uu9chyey/2/

Comment: Will it work without fixed px widths etc? Trying now...

Comment: If we can get that to work with % than it's a winner

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36783414/3597276

Comment: Sorry let me be more clear... I didn't mean necessarily overtly setting % margins for the items. More like setting % widths and then letting the resulting space between  achieve an equivalent result... does that make more sense?

Comment: The margins guarantee the gaps between flex items. Without them, percentage-based items can blend into each other: https://jsfiddle.net/uu9chyey/3/ ... You me be better off with a script.

Comment: Right but remember... we're trying to let the solution be agnostic of the TOTAL number of items, but we can definitely know the number of items/row at various breakpoints and adjust the % width accordingly to prevent them smashing together. Does that help? I'm thinking `:nth-child()` might be able to come to the rescue...

Comment: ^ I think that amounts to saying: Can we use `:nth-child()` to force a "row break" for the last item in each row?

Comment: Yes, I've used `:nth-child()` before in similar situations. If you know the total items per row, that's makes a solution much easier.

Comment: Definitely. We don't know the total count. But we can definitely decide how many / row at each breakpoint. For sure. Sorry if that wasn't clear initially

Comment: See my answer here for an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32802202/3597276

Comment: ah. `inline-block` I'll revisit that idea and maybe comment on the other answer to avoid getting too off-topic here

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the use of pseudos using margins to position the elements.

The first element is a special case, and needs a margin-left; all the others have only margin-right.

But this solution won't work with wrapping enabled. (There is no way to target the first element of the second and following rows)

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex > div {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.flex > div:first-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Calculate the difference and add a `margin-left` to the left element and a `margin-right` to the right element. Though I know you wanted an HTML/CSS solution, you can do this with JavaScript and make it perfectly responsive or just feel out the margin sizes with HTML/CSS.

## HTML

```
<div class="box" id="element"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

## JS

```
window.addEventListener('load', setMargins);

var boxClass = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

function setMargins() {
    var element = document.getElementById('element');
    var widthOfElement = element.clientWidth;
    var sizeOfEachMargin = (window.innerWidth - (widthOfElement * 3)) / 4;

    for (var i = 0; i < boxClass.length; i++) {
        boxClass[i].style.marginLeft = sizeOfEachMargin + 'px';
    }
}
```

Comment: For this answer to be useful for the OP, you should add some code samples to illustrate how it should be done.

Comment: @Brandon will you please un-down-vote my comment now?

Comment: I didn't downvote or upvote it. I saw it in the review queue, added a comment and passed the review.

Comment: @Brandon what is the review queue?

Comment: When you get 2000 reputation you earn access to the review queues which allow you to approve or reject other people's posts that have been flagged for review.

Comment: @Brandon oh ok thanks