# Equal space between flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to put a full unit of space on both sides of all items, including the first and last?

I am trying to find a way to have equal spacing around flexbox children.

In [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) it seems like the nearest thing is `justify-content: space-around`. It says that:

> `space-around`: items are evenly distributed in the line with equal
>   space around them. Note that visually the spaces aren't equal, since
>   all the items have equal space on both sides. **The first item will
>   have one unit of space against the container edge, but two units of
>   space between the next item**  because that next item has its own
>   spacing that applies.

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287771/justify-content-space-between-with-equal-space-between-first-and-last-items-als         It has a similar question.

Comment: @RajeshP the 'pseudo element' method they describe is the sorta hack I'm using now

Comment: 1: Are we talking about 1 line (row) or multi-line? ... 2: Is the amount of items per row known?

Answer (score 46):

There are at least two methods for equal space between all items, including the first and last items. One method, however, doesn't yet have full browser support.

---

### pseudo-elements

Note this section from Firefox documentation:

> [In-flow `::after` and `::before` pseudo-elements are now flex
>   items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/23#CSS).

In fact, all major browsers consider pseudo-elements on a flex container to be flex items.

Knowing that, add `::before` and `::after` to your container.

With `justify-content: space-between` and zero-width pseudo-elements, the visible flex items will appear evenly spaced.

```css
flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

flex-container::before {
  content: "";
}

flex-container::after {
  content: "";
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
flex-container {
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
flex-item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

---

### `space-evenly`

The [CSS Box Alignment Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/), which is the W3C's unfinished proposal to establish a common set of alignment properties for use across all box models, provides the `space-evenly` value for use with the `justify-content` and `align-content` properties.

> [**4.3. Distributed Alignment: the `stretch`, `space-between`,
>   `space-around`, and `space-evenly`
>   keywords**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#distribution-values)
>
> **`space-evenly`**
>
> The alignment subjects are evenly distributed in the alignment
>   container, with a full-size space on either end.
>
> The alignment subjects are distributed so that the spacing between any two adjacent alignment subjects, before the first alignment subject, and after the
>   last alignment subject is the same.

As of this writing, however, it looks like `space-evenly` **only works in Firefox and Chrome**.

```css
flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
flex-container {
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
flex-item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

Also, here's a useful demo from the [MDN **`justify-content`** page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) for testing `space-evenly` and other values in your browser. https://jsfiddle.net/gkrsr86n/

Answer (score 17):

This is a perfect use case for `flex-basis` and `justify-content: space-between` if you know how many components will be in your row beforehand. Specify a flex-basis percentage on your flex-items that totals less than 100% for all items. The leftover percentages will become margins.

No psuedo elements, child selectors or padding/margin.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;


}
span {
  flex-basis: 32%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: If there's text in the red boxes and you want to even up the space between the chunks of text (i.e. no red boxes--homogeneous background), add this to the span tag: `max-width: max-content`.

Comment: So they go hand in hand

Comment: Read more on MDN docs: [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis). This is the way, I've never used/understood this before.

Answer (score 15):

You can do this by setting the `padding` of the flex container and the `margin` of the flex items:

```
.container { 
  display: flex;   
  padding: 0 1%;
}
.item { 
  flex: 1; 
  margin: 0 1%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/danieldilly/pen/PjgRbe

Comment: just what I needed!

Answer (score 9):

In firefox only there is a `space-evenly` value for `justify-content` that does this.

It's in the CSS3 working draft

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#valdef-align-content-space-evenly

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
}
span {
  width: 20%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: cool!  I tried it in firefox and it totally works!  Issue is that this is mostly for chrome..   :/

Comment: @Alexis yeah, it will be a great addition. not sure when others are going to pick it up. Added the w3c css3 working draft showing the property.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.list_wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.list_item {
  width: 24%;
  margin-right: 0.8%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.list_item:nth-child(4n+1) {
  margin-left: 0.8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list_wrap">
  <div class="list_item"></div>
  <div class="list_item"></div>
  <div class="list_item"></div>
  <div class="list_item"></div>
  <div class="list_item"></div>
  <div class="list_item"></div>
  <div class="list_item"></div>
  <div class="list_item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use css `flex: 1;` for items you want to be equal by width.

Answer (score -2):

You can use flexbox's all property form here. this is perfect example for how to use complete flex property with example
http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Comment: It is simply a link to an external resource, which is not recommended. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to maximize the chance to have your answers upvoted