# Do flexboxes generate :before and :after?

Tags: css, flexbox, pseudo-class

Curiosity question, can't find any answer on the net.

I use a lot of `:before` and `:after` in my CSS so I declared this at the beginning of my style sheet :

```
:before, :after {
   content: "";
}
```

This way, I don't have to declare `content` each time I need a pseudo-class.

But when I did that, my elements displayed with `display: flex` are exposed differently.

Example: they are centered whereas I declared `justify-content: space-between`

So I was wondering: do `flexboxes` generate their own pseudo-classes with `content: "something"`?

Comment: Your before and after are defined so they become children of your flex container which makes them flex items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, flexboxes do not generate their own pseudo-classes with `content: "something"`. What happens here is simply the same as with all other `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements, namely that you are creating extra content. `content: ""` is not the same as `content: none`!

In this example, I give the children borders, so that you can see where they are. Without `::before` and `::after`:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
section div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div>one</div>
 <div>two</div>
</section>
```

And with `::before` and `::after`. So now you have two elements AND two pseudo elements, for a total of four pieces of content. The behaviour is completely as expected: those four bits are spread out evenly.

```css
section {display:flex; background:yellow; justify-content:space-between}
section div {border:1px solid red;}
section::before, section::after {content:""; border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<section>
 <div>one</div>
 <div>two</div>
</section>
```

If that is undesired behaviour for flexboxes, simply reset the `content` property back to `none` for those elements.

Answer (score 1):

Across box models, pseudo elements become children of the container. So when you declare `::before` / `::after` on a flex container, those pseudo elements become flex items.

If you have two actual (DOM) elements in the container, with `justify-content: space-between`, and then add `::before` and `::after` elements, you now have four flex items. Those pseudos take the edge positions, forcing the DOM elements to spread across the container.

This is actually a method that can be use to spread flex items *evenly* in the container. Not `space-between`, not `space-around`, but `space-evenly`, which allots equal space on either side of all items.

Since `space-evenly` isn't widely supported yet, the pseudo-element hack is a solid workaround.

More details here: [Equal space between flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45134400/3597276)