# How can I align my display: flex without overriding the margin attribute?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying out flex for the first time. I thought this would align perfectly, with even spaces in between, but for some reason the `margin-right` acts on the last box.

How can I get them to space evenly with the correct `margin-right: 3%` on box one and two, but not three, without overriding margin using: `margin-right: 0% !important;`.

I get this:

[image: flex issue where boxes do not allign]

What am I doing wrong?

```css
/* boxes sit in a page area div */
#pageArea {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0% 0 0% 0;
}


/* flex */
.evenly {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: solid;
}

.item {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: gray;
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
  margin: 0 3% 5% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="evenly">
  <div class="item" id="item1">Item One</div>
  <div class="item" id="item2">Item # Two</div>
  <div class="item" id="item3">Item Three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using margin set the width of your items only. this will cause the space-between property to work correctly

```
.item {
  white-space:nowrap;
  background:gray;
  width: 30%;   /* reduced to 30% */
  border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
  /*margin: 0 3% 5% 0;*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
.item { margin-right: 3% }
```

use

```
.item + .item { margin-left: 3% }
```

The original selector is saying: *all items get a right margin*

The revised selector is saying: *only items that immediately follow an item get a left margin*. This excludes a left margin on the first item.

```css
#pageArea {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0% 0 0% 0;
}
.evenly {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: solid;
}

.item {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: gray;
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
  margin: 0 0 5% 0;
}

.item+.item {
  margin-left: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="evenly">
  <div class="item" id="item1">Item One</div>
  <div class="item" id="item2">Item # Two</div>
  <div class="item" id="item3">Item Three</div>
</div>
```

And keep in mind that percentage margins and padding in flexbox behave differently across browsers. [Why doesn't percentage padding work on flex items in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36783414/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* boxes sit in a page area div */
#pageArea {
    width: 96%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0% 0 0% 0;
}  

/* flex */
.evenly {
      display:flex;
      justify-content:space-between;
      border:solid;
}

.item {
      white-space:nowrap;
      background:gray;
      width: 32%; /* (100 - 3*2)/3 */
      border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
      margin: 0 0 5% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="evenly">
  <div class="item" id="item1">Item One</div>
  <div class="item" id="item2">Item # Two</div>
  <div class="item" id="item3">Item Three</div>
</div>
```

The `justify-content:space-between;` can calculate the space automatically, no need to use the margin.