# FlexBox - container width not expanding when using percent margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I built a simple page using FlexBox CSS, and I don't understand why when I use a percent margin on one of the items, the width of the container is not expanding.

Note: Problems exists in Chrome / FireFox.

Code Pen: https://codepen.io/dsomekh/pen/QvGvrq

Example:

```
<html>
<style>
.page{
    display:flex;
    /*border: 5px solid orange;*/
}

.container{

display:flex;
border: 5px solid orange;
}
.item_left{
display:flex;
margin-right:25%;
}

.item_right{
display:flex;

}
</style>
<div class="page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item_left">Left</div>
        <div class="item_right">Right</div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/ *"Authors should avoid using percentages in paddings or margins on flex items entirely, as they will get different behavior in different browsers."* What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: From what I know, defining the margin as % is better for a responsive layout. Currently I am using px to define the margin, is there a better solution?

Comment: Use viewport units `vw`/`vh` .... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmOwPW

Comment: Thanks, i will look into that!

Comment: Added a sample too, in previous comment. I can post that as an answer if you like

Comment: Sure, you can post it as an answer. I think you should also include the reference Michael gave.

Comment: @DavidSomekh there is also always `em` and `rem` for relative margins. nothing wrong with using `px` if it works with your layout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36783190/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Michael Coker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619266/flexbox-container-width-not-expanding-when-using-percent-margin#comment74287687_43619266) commented, *Authors should avoid using percentages in paddings or margins on flex items entirely, as they will get different behavior in different browsers.* ([CSS Flexbox margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#item-margins))

When using percent we often relate that to the viewport width, so with that in mind, viewport units `vw`/`vh` can be a good option, since it works similar (responsive).

Stack snippet made of your Codepen sample

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  /*border: 5px solid orange;*/
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid orange;
}

.item_left {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 25vw;
}

.item_right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item_left">Left</div>
    <div class="item_right">Right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Stack snippet made of your questions code

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  /*border: 5px solid orange;*/
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid orange;
}

.item_left {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 25vw;
}

.item_right {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item_left">Left</div>
    <div class="item_right">Right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using flexbox wrong. 
try

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}

.item_left {
  flex: 1;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  margin-right:25%;
}

.item_right {
  flex: 1;
  border: 5px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="item_left">Left</div>
  <div class="item_right">Right</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code causes the two items in the container expand through the entire page. Is there some way to avoid it?

Comment: May I ask what is wrong with OP's code?

Comment: @DavidSomekh It is the lack of using `display: flex` for the `.page`, together with using `flex: 1` on the items, that cause it to use full page width. Remove the `flex: 1` and you'll see yet another layout.