# Why are my flex items wrapping off the screen?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

I have a flex nav and it's wrapping to the left and partially off of the screen. Does anyone with more experience know what could be causing this? I can't figure out why it's doing this.

```css
header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, .8);
  border-bottom: 12px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: center;
}

header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border: 8px solid black;
}

header h1,
nav a {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: arial;
}

header nav {
  display: none;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited,
a,
h1 {
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  header {
    height: 120px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  header h1 {
    margin: 0 0 0 8%;
    font-size: 2em;
    align-self: flex-start;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  header nav {
    display: block;
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin: 0 8% 0 0;
  }
  nav ul li {
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 4px 1%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .characters:hover {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  }
  .drop-menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 38px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, .8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .02);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  }
  .characters:hover .drop-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .drop-menu li {
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  footer nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Seraph Chronicles</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li class="main-nav-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav-item"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav-item characters">
        <a href="characters.html">Characters</a>
        <ul class="drop-menu">
          <li><a href="ethanClarke.html">Ethan Clarke</a></li>
          <li><a href="serenaKiriaga.html">Serena Kiriaga</a></li>
          <li><a href="MarcusFlynn.html">Marcus Flynn</a></li>
          <li><a href="EmilyAshdown.html">Emily Ashdown</a></li>
          <li><a href="MilesWest.html">Director Miles West</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="main-nav-item"><a href="auther.html">Author</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ca75sqzc/17/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

Don't use percentages on flex item margins. Use another unit, such as `px` or `em`.

[revised demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ca75sqzc/19/)

---

### Explanation

When you make the primary container (`.header`) a flex container, its children become flex items.

These are the two children: `h1` and `nav` (red borders added below)

[image]

Each nav item (`li`) has a horizontal margin (1% on each side).

```
nav ul li{
   border-radius: 8px;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 4px 1%;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

This causes them to overflow the container.

Then, because the container has `justify-content: flex-end`, the items are aligned to the container's right edge. This means the overflow occurs on the left side (see image above).

On smaller screens, the nav element wraps to the left edge of the header, and the overflowing items go out of view:

[image]

If you switch to `justify-content: flex-start`, the items overflow on the right side.

[image][image]

---

But ***the real problem*** is actually this:

> Why isn't the `ul` container expanding to accommodate the `li` children?

The answer appears to be the use of percentages for the horizontal margins.

```
nav ul {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   margin: 0 8% 0 0;
}

nav ul li {
   border-radius: 8px;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 4px 1%;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

The container is not recognizing this unit on the margins and, therefore, not expanding.

Note that the [flexbox spec recommends against using percentage margins and padding on flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36783414/3597276).

> [**4.2. Flex Item Margins and
>   Paddings**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#item-margins)
>
> Authors should avoid using percentages in paddings or margins on flex
>   items entirely, as they will get different behavior in different browsers.

Once you switch to non-percentage units on your margins, everything seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following in your CSS:

```
nav ul{
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: flex-end; */
  margin: 0 8% 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just erase `justify-content: flex-end;` from the rule for `nav ul` in the media query section:

```css
header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, .8);
  border-bottom: 12px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: center;
}

header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border: 8px solid black;
}

header h1,
nav a {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: arial;
}

header nav {
  display: none;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited,
a,
h1 {
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  header {
    height: 120px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  header h1 {
    margin: 0 0 0 8%;
    font-size: 2em;
    align-self: flex-start;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  header nav {
    display: block;
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 8% 0 0;
  }
  nav ul li {
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 4px 1%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .characters:hover {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  }
  .drop-menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 38px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, .8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .02);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  }
  .characters:hover .drop-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .drop-menu li {
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  footer nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Seraph Chronicles</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li class="main-nav-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav-item"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav-item characters">
        <a href="characters.html">Characters</a>
        <ul class="drop-menu">
          <li><a href="ethanClarke.html">Ethan Clarke</a></li>
          <li><a href="serenaKiriaga.html">Serena Kiriaga</a></li>
          <li><a href="MarcusFlynn.html">Marcus Flynn</a></li>
          <li><a href="EmilyAshdown.html">Emily Ashdown</a></li>
          <li><a href="MilesWest.html">Director Miles West</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="main-nav-item"><a href="auther.html">Author</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7dubc44L/

Comment: For reasons explained in my answer, this doesn't work. You simply shifted the hidden items to the right side.