# Flexbox children's children overflowing

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

The children of my Flex Box have Children themselves, for one of these children (the `<img>` I use the `object-fit:cover` to make sure all of the image tiles will be of the same height/width).

The problem is that the second child (`<h4>` tag) is not being contained within the Flex Box and appears to overflow.

My efforts thus far have resulted in the `<h4>` tag fitting but the `object-fit: cover` ceasing to work.

Is this possible to do?

```css
#content {
  margin-left: 18%;
  margin-right: 18%;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}

h1.page-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 39px 0px 39px 150px;
}

.image-pane {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.image-tile {
  margin: 1%;
  width: 48%;
}
span.image-tile>img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.image-text {
  font-family: aftaSansRegular;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1 class="page-title">
    Galleries
  </h1>

  <div class="image-pane">
    <span class="image-tile">
      <img src="http://i.turner.ncaa.com/ncaa/big/2016/03/21/379123/1458530071096-mbk-312-wisconsin-xavier-1920.jpg-379123.960x540.jpg" alt="Basketball Image 01"/>
      <h4 class="image-text">
        Sports
      </h4>
    </span>

    <span class="image-tile">
      <img src="https://www.bahn.com/en/view/mdb/pv/agenturservice/2011/mdb_22990_ice_3_schnellfahrstrecke_nuernberg_-_ingolstadt_1000x500_cp_0x144_1000x644.jpg" alt="Train Image 01"/>
      <h4 class="image-text">
        Models
      </h4>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

When replying could you please provide an explanation of why it occurs this way so I can understand it rather then just correct it :'P

Comment: You placed block element within the inline one

Comment: How does it overflow? ... Looks good on Chrome/Firefox for me

Comment: Both of the <h4> tags are placed outside of the grey box that wraps around the images. I am on Chrome 60.0.3112.113

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you tell an element to be `height: 100%`, it occupies the full height of the container. As a result, there is no space left for siblings. That's why the `h4` is being rendered outside the container.

A simple fix is to make the child of the flex container (`.image-tile`) also a flex container.

Then the children (the image and the heading) become flex items. With `flex-direction: column` they stack vertically.

Because initial settings on flex items are [**`flex-shrink: 1`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) and [**`flex-wrap: nowrap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap), the image with `height: 100%` is allowed to shrink in order for all items to fit inside the container.

You then need to override the flex minimum height default (`min-height: auto`) so the image and heading both fit inside the container. More details here:

- [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

Also, as a side note, if you're going to use percentage margins (or padding) inside a flex container, consider this:

- [Why doesn't percentage padding / margin work on flex items in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36783190/3597276)

```css
#content {
  margin-left: 18%;
  margin-right: 18%;
}

h1.page-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 39px 0px 39px 150px;
}

.image-pane {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.image-tile {
  display: flex;           /* new */
  flex-direction: column;  /* new */
  margin: 1%;
  width: 48%;
}

span.image-tile > img {
  min-height: 0;           /* new */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.image-text {
  font-family: aftaSansRegular;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1 class="page-title">
    Galleries
  </h1>

  <div class="image-pane">
    <span class="image-tile">
      <img src="http://i.turner.ncaa.com/ncaa/big/2016/03/21/379123/1458530071096-mbk-312-wisconsin-xavier-1920.jpg-379123.960x540.jpg" alt="Basketball Image 01"/>
      <h4 class="image-text">
        Sports
      </h4>
    </span>

    <span class="image-tile">
      <img src="https://www.bahn.com/en/view/mdb/pv/agenturservice/2011/mdb_22990_ice_3_schnellfahrstrecke_nuernberg_-_ingolstadt_1000x500_cp_0x144_1000x644.jpg" alt="Train Image 01"/>
      <h4 class="image-text">
        Models
      </h4>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Image height 100% is creating issue because 100% height occupied by image itself due to parent flex property as flex makes child's height 100%. That's why title goes away from parent div.

So if you want to make it perfect, add some pixels height in image like 300px or anything according to your design.

```css
#content {
  margin-left: 18%;
  margin-right: 18%;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}

h1.page-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 39px 0px 39px 150px;
}

.image-pane {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.image-tile {
  margin: 1%;
  width: 48%;
}
span.image-tile>img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.image-text {
  font-family: aftaSansRegular;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1 class="page-title">
    Galleries
  </h1>

  <div class="image-pane">
    <span class="image-tile">
      <img src="http://i.turner.ncaa.com/ncaa/big/2016/03/21/379123/1458530071096-mbk-312-wisconsin-xavier-1920.jpg-379123.960x540.jpg" alt="Basketball Image 01"/>
      <h4 class="image-text">
        Sports
      </h4>
    </span>

    <span class="image-tile">
      <img src="https://www.bahn.com/en/view/mdb/pv/agenturservice/2011/mdb_22990_ice_3_schnellfahrstrecke_nuernberg_-_ingolstadt_1000x500_cp_0x144_1000x644.jpg" alt="Train Image 01"/>
      <h4 class="image-text">
        Models
      </h4>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did come to this conclusion shortly before checking this post, thank you very much. My only concern is that having a static value for pixels means I will need to have multiple @media's to manage varying resolutions?

Comment: Michael_B gave perfect answer for the height.