# CSS flex layout: wrapping when adding padding or margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a navigation bar, a logo at the left and the links centered in the remaining space. I followed the instructions in this thread:
[In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties/33856609#33856609)
and used `margin:auto;` for the `ul` in order to get it centered. This worked fine so far but when I add `margin` or `padding` anywhere inside the `ul` the list of links wraps. I tried `box-sizing:border-box;` for the `ul` but no success. How can I fix this?
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/30sy5dmy/5/

```css
nav img {
  height: 60px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.links {
  margin: auto;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 2%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="https://teststein.000webhostapp.com/Logo.png">
  <ul class="links">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

The list items are wrapping because you're using percentage margins.

When you give the items horizontal margins of 2%, the browser calculates the length of that 2% *after* the size of the container has been determined. In other words, the percentages are not factored into the container width.

Therefore, when the 2% length is added to the items, the total length exceeds that of the container and wrapping occurs.

### Solution #1: `white-space: nowrap`

One way to fix the problem is by suppressing line breaks in the container using [the **`white-space`** property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space). This forces all items to stay on the same line, overflowing the container if necessary.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px dashed black;   /* for demo only */
}

nav img {
  height: 60px;
}

.links {
  margin: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;     /* NEW */
  padding: 0;              /* optional; remove default indentation on list elements */
  border: 1px dashed red;  /* for demo only */
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 2%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-60-60-1.jpg">
  <ul class="links">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

### Solution #2: Don't use percentage values

If you use any value other than percentages, the list items won't wrap because, unlike percentage values, they can expand the container for accommodation.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px dashed black;   /* for demo only */
}

nav img {
  height: 60px;
}

.links {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;              /* optional; remove default indentation on list elements */
  border: 1px dashed red;  /* for demo only */
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 1em;            /* adjustment */
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-60-60-1.jpg">
  <ul class="links">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

### Solution #3: Use flexbox

An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-direction: row` and `flex-wrap: nowrap`. This means that flex items will line up horizontally and cannot wrap.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px dashed black;   /* for demo only */
}

nav img {
  height: 60px;
}

.links {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;              /* optional; remove default indentation on list elements */
  border: 1px dashed red;  /* for demo only */
  display: flex;           /* new */
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 1em;            /* adjustment; avoid percentage margins on flex items;
                               see this post:
                               https://stackoverflow.com/q/36783190/3597276 */
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-60-60-1.jpg">
  <ul class="links">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

### Solution #4: Clean and Efficient Method

This solution attempts to use the least possible code to achieve the goal. Hope it helps.

```css
nav             { display: flex; align-items: center; }
nav img         { height: 60px; }
a:first-of-type { margin-left: auto; }
a:last-of-type  { margin-right: auto; }
a + a           { margin-left: 1em; }
```

```html
<nav>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-60-60-1.jpg">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this extensive explanation, much appreciated! Learned a lot when reading it. Solution #4 is brilliant. Using margin-left and margin-right for the the first and last link didn't come into my mind.

Comment: I noticed that you are the author of this answer too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties/33856609#33856609
Extemely useful, I have it in my bookmarks. Thanks for elaborating this.

Comment: You're welcome. I was trying to explain *main axis* alignment. I'm glad you found it useful. Here's the other side of the coin (the *cross axis*): https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `display: flex` to the `links`, and then, as using percent for margins on flex items doesn't render the same cross browser, use i.e. viewport units instead.

```css
nav img {
  height: 60px;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.links {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 2vw;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-60-60-1.jpg">
  <ul class="links">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @LGSon This works perfectly, an easy and clear solution. Many thanks!

Comment: @VXp "moved to the right exactly by the width of the img" That's exactly what I want it to do, the ul should be centered in the **remaining space**

Comment: @Michael_B Am aware of that :) ... and the inline block might still wrap if long text in links and narrow screens, so found flex most appropriate