# Distributing images with flexbox so images are equal height using jquery - Firefox vs Chrome behaviour

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I'm using jquery to calculate the aspect ratio of images and setting that as the `flex-grow` value so that all images within the flexbox appear the same  height while filling the width of the container.

This works great in Firefox, but has different behaviour in Chrome.

In Firefox, all images are the same height and maintain their aspect ratios.

In Chrome, all images appear to have the same width as in Firefox, but they are vertically stretched to the height of the tallest item, 500px.

How can I fix how this looks in Chrome?

```js
$('div.pack').css({
    "display": "flex"
  })
  .children().each(function() {
    var aspect = this.naturalWidth / this.naturalHeight;
    $(this).wrap('<div style="display:flex; flex: 0% ' + aspect + ' 1;" />')
  });
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.pack > div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='pack'>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x150"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x500"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add `align-items: flex-start` to the `div` wrapper's CSS, or else Chrome will *stretch* the `img` as the default value for `align-items` is just that, `stretch`.

*I also changed the order of the shorthand flex properties to their correct position*

*Also note, [using percent for margin and padding on flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783190/why-doesnt-percentage-padding-margin-work-on-flex-items-in-firefox) might render different based on the fact that the specs. allows it, and it is recommended not to.*

Stack snippet

```js
$('div.pack').css({
    "display": "flex"
  })
  .children().each(function() {
    var aspect = this.naturalWidth / this.naturalHeight;
    $(this).wrap('<div style="display: flex; align-items: flex-start; flex: ' + aspect + ' 1 0%;" />')
  });
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.pack > div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='pack'>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x150"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x500"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300"/>
</div>
```

---

Another option would be to simply remove `display: flex` on the `div` wrapper's.

Stack snippet

```js
$('div.pack').css({
    "display": "flex"
  })
  .children().each(function() {
    var aspect = this.naturalWidth / this.naturalHeight;
    $(this).wrap('<div style="flex: ' + aspect + ' 1 0%;" />')
  });
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.pack > div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='pack'>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x150"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x500"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300"/>
</div>
```