# Flexbox - Make item 16:9

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a basic flexbox container with 2 items..

```css
html, body {
    margin:0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}

.item div {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  background: gold;
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="item">
<div>
<img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/any/grayscale">
</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
<div>
<img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/any/grayscale">
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Following the code at [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css) - I am trying to make the 2 items 16:9. But it is not working as expected.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the width be 50%? And why have you added extra divs?

Comment: The code from the link recommended adding a wrapper div

Comment: The browser you're using makes a difference (although possibly not for much longer).  https://stackoverflow.com/q/36783190/3597276

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `img` elements inside the child divs are altering the height. Then the padding is being applied on top of that. You'll see what I mean if you remove the `img`.

To get around this, you can add the image as: `background: url('imageurl')`. Then add: `flex-basis: 50%` to your children and voila!

Did someone say **[codepen](https://codepen.io/lewisnewson/pen/qYJave)**?