# Flexbox 16:9 images

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working with Flexbox and have simple layout

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.image-wrapper {
  flex:1;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.2%;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--  Image start  -->
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1500x1000/000/fff" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1500x1000/000/fff" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1500x1000/000/fff" alt="" />
  </div>
  <!--  Image end  -->
</div>
```

I am trying to ensure that the images are all 16:9 aspect ratio. This works without flexbox, but as soon as I make my divs flex then it no longer works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have `height:100%` on the images? The snippet works great without it.

Answer (score 1):

An initial setting of a flex container is [`flex-wrap: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap). This means that flex items will remain confined to a single line no matter what. Add `flex-wrap: wrap`.

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Also, note the following post, which may be obsolete by now, but maybe not in some browsers.

- [Why doesn't percentage padding / margin work on flex items in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36783190/3597276)

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0o89Lem6/3/)

Comment: But I want to keep them in a row, not a column

Comment: Oh, you said in your question that it "works without flexbox", so it appeared to me that you wanted the same behavior as block layout.

Comment: Just remove `flex-wrap: nowrap`. The `flex: 1 0 100%` I already added should be enough to make it work, at least in Chrome. See the link I posted for other browsers. https://jsfiddle.net/0o89Lem6/6/

Comment: Sorry, original post wasn't very clear. I meant the 16:9 aspect ratio works without flexbox, but when I put them in a flexbox layout for 3 in a row, the aspect ratio breaks