# Flex modal in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have prepared modal that works perfectly fine in Chrome, but crashes in IE.
Could you please check what am I doing wrong? I tried multiple fallback-prefixes etc, wrapping with flex-row and so on.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z2pQDsIMjqs4jWvytcVf?p=preview

```
.flex-container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.middle {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Version that works on Chrome satisfies all requirements:

- modal has to be aligned horizontally in the middle
- footer and header have static height
- when window is too big, the modal should not stretch any more
- when window is to small to show full modal, the scrollback should appear for "middle" content, so the hedr and footer will always be shown
- modal should be as small as possible to not show any blank spaces under "middle" content, so I cant set `height: 100%` on any wrapper (that would solve issue for Ie, but not for me :( )

but on IE11, when `.middle` is to big it either overflows the footer or makes the scroll appear on the whole modal.

Comment: It's possible you've made no mistakes. Check this page, there are a *ton* of bugs in IE related to flex: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: that would be sad, Its possible i have an older compilation or sth :/

Comment: possible guidance: [flex property not working in IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32239549/3597276)