# Why does this flex table works on chrome, but not on IE 11?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to make a flexible grid with scroll and a fixed header/footer without using javascript, but somehow the flex items are not working properly on IE.

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/m6oqw76e/5/

basically what I'm doing is setting everything with 100% width and using this structure:

```
.mGrid > thead > tr.hdr,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.nrm,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.alt {
    display: flex;
}
.mGrid > thead > tr.hdr > th,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.nrm > td,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.alt > td {
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    /*flex-grow: 100;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: 0px;*/
    flex: 100 0 0px;
}
```

I know IE is known for having many bugs with flex, but I'd like to know if there's any workaround to make it work.

```css
.mGrid {  border-collapse: collapse;  background-color: gainsboro;  }
.mGrid > thead > tr.hdr > th, .mGrid > tbody > tr.nrm > td, .mGrid > tbody > tr.alt > td {  border: 1px solid white;  }


/*======================================================================= basic table structure */
.mGrid {
  width: 100%;
}
.mGrid > thead,
.mGrid > tbody,
.mGrid > tfoot {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.mGrid > tbody {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.mGrid > thead > tr.hdr {
  width: calc(100% - 17px);
}
.mGrid > tbody > tr.nrm,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.alt {
  width: 100%;
}
/*======================================================================= flex not working */
.mGrid > thead > tr.hdr,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.nrm,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.alt {
  display: flex;
}
.mGrid > thead > tr.hdr > th,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.nrm > td,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.alt > td {
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /*flex-grow: 100;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 0px;*/
  flex: 100 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<table class="mGrid">
  <thead>
    <tr class="hdr">
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Nº Despesa</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Consultor</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Setor</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Empresa</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Motivo</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Data</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Hotel</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Refeição</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Veículo</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Taxi</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Outros</a></th>
      <th>Vlr Total</th>
      <th>Comprovantes OK</th>
      <th>Aprovado</th>
      <th>Status Visita</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="nrm">
      <td><span>00392-05-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na</span></td>
      <td><span>Plantão 24x7</span></td>
      <td><span>Empres</span></td>
      <td><span>Serviço</span></td>
      <td><span>06-03-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 80,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 150,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 230,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
      <td><span>00392-03-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names Names Names</span></td>
      <td><span>Plantão 24x7</span></td>
      <td><span>EMPR</span></td>
      <td><span>Serviço</span></td>
      <td><span>31-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 80,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 100,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 180,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nrm">
      <td><span>00392-02-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Names Namesnam</span></td>
      <td><span>Plantão 24x7</span></td>
      <td><span>Empres</span></td>
      <td><span>Serviço</span></td>
      <td><span>31-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 80,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 100,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 180,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
      <td><span>00392-01-02</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Names Namesnam</span></td>
      <td><span>Plantão 24x7</span></td>
      <td><span>EMPR</span></td>
      <td><span>Relacionamentos</span></td>
      <td><span>31-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 30,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 100,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 130,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nrm">
      <td><span>00392-01-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Names</span></td>
      <td><span>Plantão 24x7</span></td>
      <td><span>EMPR</span></td>
      <td><span>Relacionamentos</span></td>
      <td><span>30-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 80,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 100,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 180,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
      <td><span>00388-01-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Namesnam</span></td>
      <td><span>Requisitos</span></td>
      <td><span>Empres</span></td>
      <td><span>Serviço</span></td>
      <td><span>01-02-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 246,60</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 246,60</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nrm">
      <td><span>00387-02-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Names Namesnam</span></td>
      <td><span>Middleware</span></td>
      <td><span>Empresa Empresaempr EMPR-ESA</span></td>
      <td><span>Serviço</span></td>
      <td><span>26-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 266,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 266,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
      <td><span>00387-01-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Names Namesnam</span></td>
      <td><span>Middleware</span></td>
      <td><span>Empres</span></td>
      <td><span>Vendas</span></td>
      <td><span>25-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 185,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 185,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="pgr">
      <td colspan="16">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><span>1</span></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">2</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">3</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">4</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">5</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">6</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">7</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">8</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">9</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">10</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">...</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: BTW, IE has some bugs regarding to flex-blox. Try setting `width` to parents always you want to set `width: 100%;` in a child. I like this question so I will wait for the answer.

Comment: Interestingly, the word-wrap seems to not be working at all, even if you set a fixed width on the cell

Comment: Honestly, I think the workaround is a `<table>`.

Comment: Unfortunately, my changes on HTML are very limited, I am using an ASP.NET GridView, and it renders as seen on my snippet.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32239549/3597276

Comment: not duplicate due to the issue being a combination of table and flex conflicts (see accepted answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update this css, you need to override default display property of `th`, `td` which is `display:table-cell` with `display:flex;`.

```
.mGrid > thead > tr.hdr > th,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.nrm > td,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.alt > td {
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  flex:1 1 110px; /* Updated*/
  display:flex; /* Added to override default display property*/
}
```

```css
.mGrid {  border-collapse: collapse;  background-color: gainsboro;  }
.mGrid > thead > tr.hdr > th, .mGrid > tbody > tr.nrm > td, .mGrid > tbody > tr.alt > td {  border: 1px solid white;  }


/*======================================================================= basic table structure */
.mGrid {
  width: 100%;
}
.mGrid > thead,
.mGrid > tbody,
.mGrid > tfoot {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.mGrid > tbody {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.mGrid > thead > tr.hdr {
  width: calc(100% - 17px);
}
.mGrid > tbody > tr.nrm,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.alt {
  width: 100%;
}
/*======================================================================= flex not working */
.mGrid > thead > tr.hdr,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.nrm,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.alt {
  display: flex;
}
.mGrid > thead > tr.hdr > th,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.nrm > td,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.alt > td {
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  flex:1 1 110px;
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<table class="mGrid">
  <thead>
    <tr class="hdr">
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Nº Despesa</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Consultor</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Setor</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Empresa</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Motivo</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Data</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Hotel</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Refeição</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Veículo</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Taxi</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Outros</a></th>
      <th>Vlr Total</th>
      <th>Comprovantes OK</th>
      <th>Aprovado</th>
      <th>Status Visita</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="nrm">
      <td><span>00392-05-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na</span></td>
      <td><span>Plantão 24x7</span></td>
      <td><span>Empres</span></td>
      <td><span>Serviço</span></td>
      <td><span>06-03-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 80,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 150,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 230,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
      <td><span>00392-03-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names Names Names</span></td>
      <td><span>Plantão 24x7</span></td>
      <td><span>EMPR</span></td>
      <td><span>Serviço</span></td>
      <td><span>31-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 80,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 100,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 180,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nrm">
      <td><span>00392-02-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Names Namesnam</span></td>
      <td><span>Plantão 24x7</span></td>
      <td><span>Empres</span></td>
      <td><span>Serviço</span></td>
      <td><span>31-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 80,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 100,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 180,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
      <td><span>00392-01-02</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Names Namesnam</span></td>
      <td><span>Plantão 24x7</span></td>
      <td><span>EMPR</span></td>
      <td><span>Relacionamentos</span></td>
      <td><span>31-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 30,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 100,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 130,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nrm">
      <td><span>00392-01-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Names</span></td>
      <td><span>Plantão 24x7</span></td>
      <td><span>EMPR</span></td>
      <td><span>Relacionamentos</span></td>
      <td><span>30-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 80,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 100,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 180,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
      <td><span>00388-01-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Namesnam</span></td>
      <td><span>Requisitos</span></td>
      <td><span>Empres</span></td>
      <td><span>Serviço</span></td>
      <td><span>01-02-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 246,60</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 246,60</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nrm">
      <td><span>00387-02-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Names Namesnam</span></td>
      <td><span>Middleware</span></td>
      <td><span>Empresa Empresaempr EMPR-ESA</span></td>
      <td><span>Serviço</span></td>
      <td><span>26-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 266,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 266,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
      <td><span>00387-01-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Names Namesnam</span></td>
      <td><span>Middleware</span></td>
      <td><span>Empres</span></td>
      <td><span>Vendas</span></td>
      <td><span>25-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 185,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 185,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="pgr">
      <td colspan="16">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><span>1</span></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">2</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">3</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">4</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">5</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">6</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">7</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">8</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">9</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">10</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">...</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: This works! Now I just need to find out why the word-wrap is not working. Which is another problem that goes beyond this question scope.

Comment: word-wrap working again after setting `span, a { width: 100% }`

Answer (score 1):

Use prefix for IE
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx

```
display: -ms-flexbox;
-ms-flex-align: start;
```

etc..

```css
.mGrid {  
  border-collapse: collapse;  
  background-color: gainsboro;  
 }
 
.mGrid > thead > tr.hdr > th, 
.mGrid > tbody > tr.nrm > td, 
.mGrid > tbody > tr.alt > td {  
  border: 1px solid white;  
 }


/*======================================================================= basic table structure */
.mGrid {
  width: 100%;
}
.mGrid > thead,
.mGrid > tbody,
.mGrid > tfoot {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.mGrid > tbody {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.mGrid > thead > tr.hdr {
  width: calc(100% - 17px);
}
.mGrid > tbody > tr.nrm,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.alt {
  width: 100%;
}
/*======================================================================= flex not working */
.mGrid > thead > tr.hdr,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.nrm,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.alt {
  display: flex;
}
.mGrid > thead > tr.hdr > th,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.nrm > td,
.mGrid > tbody > tr.alt > td {
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /*flex-grow: 100;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 0px;*/
  flex: 100 0 0px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
-ms-flex-align: start;
}
```

```html
<table class="mGrid">
  <thead>
    <tr class="hdr">
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Nº Despesa</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Consultor</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Setor</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Empresa</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Motivo</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Data</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Hotel</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Refeição</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Veículo</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Taxi</a></th>
      <th><a href="http://google.com">Outros</a></th>
      <th>Vlr Total</th>
      <th>Comprovantes OK</th>
      <th>Aprovado</th>
      <th>Status Visita</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="nrm">
      <td><span>00392-05-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na</span></td>
      <td><span>Plantão 24x7</span></td>
      <td><span>Empres</span></td>
      <td><span>Serviço</span></td>
      <td><span>06-03-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 80,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 150,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 230,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
      <td><span>00392-03-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names Names Names</span></td>
      <td><span>Plantão 24x7</span></td>
      <td><span>EMPR</span></td>
      <td><span>Serviço</span></td>
      <td><span>31-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 80,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 100,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 180,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nrm">
      <td><span>00392-02-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Names Namesnam</span></td>
      <td><span>Plantão 24x7</span></td>
      <td><span>Empres</span></td>
      <td><span>Serviço</span></td>
      <td><span>31-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 80,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 100,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 180,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
      <td><span>00392-01-02</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Names Namesnam</span></td>
      <td><span>Plantão 24x7</span></td>
      <td><span>EMPR</span></td>
      <td><span>Relacionamentos</span></td>
      <td><span>31-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 30,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 100,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 130,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nrm">
      <td><span>00392-01-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Names</span></td>
      <td><span>Plantão 24x7</span></td>
      <td><span>EMPR</span></td>
      <td><span>Relacionamentos</span></td>
      <td><span>30-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 80,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 100,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 180,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
      <td><span>00388-01-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Namesnam</span></td>
      <td><span>Requisitos</span></td>
      <td><span>Empres</span></td>
      <td><span>Serviço</span></td>
      <td><span>01-02-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 246,60</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 246,60</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nrm">
      <td><span>00387-02-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Names Namesnam</span></td>
      <td><span>Middleware</span></td>
      <td><span>Empresa Empresaempr EMPR-ESA</span></td>
      <td><span>Serviço</span></td>
      <td><span>26-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 266,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 266,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
      <td><span>00387-01-01</span></td>
      <td><span>Names na Names Namesnam</span></td>
      <td><span>Middleware</span></td>
      <td><span>Empres</span></td>
      <td><span>Vendas</span></td>
      <td><span>25-01-2017</span></td>
      <td><span>Não</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 185,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 0,00</span></td>
      <td><span>R$ 185,00</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Sim</span></td>
      <td><span>Liquidado</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="pgr">
      <td colspan="16">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><span>1</span></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">2</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">3</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">4</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">5</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">6</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">7</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">8</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">9</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">10</a></td>
              <td><a href="http://google.com">...</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Good answer, It works. I will edit it to add a code snippet.

Comment: sorry, it started to give the same width for all cells, but it's still not working properly.

Comment: being more specific, the flex-grow property is not working