# Nested flexbox wrap not working in IE11 and Safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a nested navbar in flexbox and I like to support IE11.
I use flex-direction: row; and flex-wrap: wrap; on .navbar.
And I do the same on the .nav items.
Everything seems to work fine on Chrome and Firefox but not in IE11 or Safari.

In IE11 and Safari when I shrink the screen the items in the .navbar snap to a new row. But this does not happen with the items in .nav.
The items in .nav stay inline and break out of the navbars box.

Is it possible to fix this issue?

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.left {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.right {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav li {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: .8em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>My Company</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Settings</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see the exact same behavior in both Chrome and IE11.

Comment: That's strange I had the expected behaviour in Chrome before but this doesn't work since I added prefixes. Firefox still works see https://jsfiddle.net/sgroen/6fwdhjsq.

Comment: Careful using the *flex* property in IE: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32239549/3597276

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a solution for this problem. I removed flex: 0 0 auto; from the .nav and now everything works as it should.
I also modified the markup too keep things as simple as possible.

See example below:

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.logo {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav li {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
  padding: .8em 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="logo">My Company</li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Settings</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav right">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```