# Why flex container `flex: 1 0 0px` collapses on Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

On Chrome I encountered Flexbox behaviour I don't understand. When a flex child which is also a flex container has `flex: 1 0 0px`, it collapses itself and it's contents.

Even though `flex-basis` is set to `0px`, as far as I understand setting `flex-grow` to `1` (first number in `flex` shorthand) should make the item grow, when needed.

In my example `.bottom-container` has `height` set to `300px`. That `height` is respected on Firefox, but collapsed to `0px` on Chrome. Why?

```css
.top-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.middle-container {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.bottom-container {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <div class="middle-container">
    <div class="bottom-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle-container">
    <div class="bottom-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Flex: 1 0 0 ;` tells `flex-basis:0;`, i would say, chrome has the right behavior :(

Comment: @G-Cyr: But doesn't set `flex-grow: 1` should make the item growable when needed? Sometimes I need to set `flex-basis: 0` to make sure all flex children have exactly the same size.

Comment: it is not coherent, sizing it to zero and allow it to grow at the same time, use auto for the flex-basis value, then each flex setting  works as expected ;) It is like : width:0; max-width:100%; there is a conflict in the logic

Comment: @G-Cyr: Yeah, definitely `flex: 1 0 0` is not clear declaration of what it wants to accomplish. But it's a valid declaration - the basis size is 0px and then grow to use all remaining space - and I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: There is no guidance in the flexbox spec about how browsers should interpret different units on `flex-basis` values. I wouldn't recommend a unitless value even though you are correct, it is a valid declaration.

Comment: I did not mention it was not valid, but not coherent (clear). This is a young spec and you can expect for a while to see different interpretation from a browser engine to another one . *IE6 told me long time ago to be as much as specific as possible to avoid unexpected behavior (and avoid totally the buggy ones)*. If it is not working, it might have been to do with the way it is implemented, and flex-basis overides the flex grow value here .... it should be fine somedays , obviously not yet ;) . Advice IMHO : **avoid it** at this time

Comment: @G-Cyr: I didn't think unitless `0` makes any different. I re-phrased the question to have `0px` instead of `0` - the effect is the same.

Comment: @G-Cyr, my last comment was to Robert, in case you think it was a response to your comment.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like i made things more confused to you. Mickael_B answers gives you an approach to follow, ;)

Comment: @Robert, unitless `flex-basis` values make a BIG difference, especially in IE. See the third bullet point in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32239549/3597276

Comment: @G-Cyr: And about coherency: what is the clearest way to describe the following layout with Flexbox: all flex children should be of the same size, no matter what size are their contents. So far I've been using `flex: 1 0 0` for that.

Comment: When i wish to spray evenly flex children on a col or a row, i use flex:1; on its own. just because too much flex kills flex. ;) The way i see it , when i use 0, it is to mean 0, no matter the units, and as said, % size needs a parent with a size set to be calculated, else it is much alike % of null.  Flex is a usefull grid system, so is the table-layout and the CSS grid too, but none are magic :( . My english is not good enough to go in detailled & subtil discussion how flex:1 0 0 ; should behave, be usedwhen, why. CSS is very flexible and breaks easily. it's a virtual world of compromis ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `flex-basis` component.

When you have `flex-basis: 0`, Chrome and Firefox compute to `flex-basis: 0px`.

However, the pixel value breaks your layout in Chrome.

Instead, for cross-browser compatibility, use this:

```
flex: 1 0 0%
```

Comment: The part I don't understand is why `px` value breaks the layout in Chrome?

Comment: It's how Chrome renders `px` vs `%` units. Forget about `flex-basis` for a minute. Use `height` instead. Same thing. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooXEvO

Comment: There is a history of Chrome / Safari and Firefox rendering heights differently, especially in flex containers. https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B - that would essentially be the same as saying `flex: 1 0 auto` because `0%` height is not computable because the parent has no height (and it's layout is columnar). That, and `flex: 1 0 auto` makes a lot more sense from a readability perspective than `flex: 1 0 0%`.

Comment: That's not necessarily correct. Some (maybe most) major browsers now use the computed height on the parent to determine the percentage height on the child. See the link I just posted above.

Comment: @Michael_B:  I see your solution works, but I still don't understand why. The post you linked (https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276) explains why setting `height` value in percentages on a child isn't valid until the parent has explicitly `height` too. Then why setting `flex-basis: 0%` fixes the problem in Chrome? The parent hasn't height set explicitly, so `0%` shouldn't make sense.

Comment: See the last two paragraphs before the "Solutions" section.

Comment: @Michael_B: Okay, I see it, thanks. Now I'm trying to get my head around it :).

Comment: @Michael_B: Sorry, but I still don't understand it fully. When I set `flex-basis: 0%`, judging from what you said in the other post - "Chrome looks to the parent (.item) for reference and responds: 100% of what? I don't see anything (ignoring the flex: 1 rule that is there). As a result, it applies height: auto (content height), in accordance with the spec." - Chome calculates this to `flex-basis: auto`. But setting `flex-basis: auto` produces a little different effect in Chrome than `flex-basis: 0%`. Why?

Comment: The overall point is that browsers vary in their rendering behavior, especially when the spec language is unclear. There is no definite guidance in the spec (as far as I could tell) for what browser makers should do with `flex-basis` values that are percentages, pixels or unitless. If there was, you would likely find consistent behavior in both FF and Chrome.

Comment: Instead, you find that unitless values are rendered differently in FF, Chrome, IE, Edge and Safari. They're all over the map. Hence, my recommendation in a previous comment, that you veer away from unitless values. And, test, test, test.

Comment: I understand why I should stay away from unitless values, but I do not understand why `flex-basis: 0%` is any different from `flex-basis: auto` (I tested and it is). From what you said Chrome should interpret `0%` as `auto` when parent does not have explicitly set `height`.

Comment: I also said that browsers are evolving from that traditional interpretation of the spec and taking other forms of height into consideration. I can count at least 6 differences right-off-the bat in flex rendering behavior between Chrome and FF. [Chrome even goes completely off-spec once in a while.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276) Why, you ask? I can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's the logic.

You haven't specified a height of `.top-container` so it's child elements (`.middle-container`) **cannot** grow, because there is no room for them to grow **into**, despite having `flex: 1 0 0` and, therefore, `.middle-container` elements will always maintain a height of 0.