# Flex short hand property fallback

Tags: css, internet-explorer, responsive-design, flexbox

So I'm having an issue with flexbox in css. Particularly when using the `flex` shorthand property. For example:

If I  have `flex: 0 0 30%`

In IE it just seems to get ignored in certain places. I'm using modernizr so I'm targeting the selector as:

```
.no-flex{
 .st-col-thirds {
   width: 33%;
  }
}
```

Which I thought would work... But it doesn't.

Then I tried:

```
 .no-flex{
  .st-col-thirds {
    min-width: 550px;
    margin: 5px;
   }
 }
```

This works but it's super hacked and it's not responsive.

[This is not a duplicate question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32239549/3597276)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32239549/3597276

Comment: Since those _certain places_ you mention is important how/where, post a code snippet reproducing the issues you describe, and we will be able to see which specific bug is present, if any.